# CakeDC Users create a custom login url or extend the default with url paramter

Tags: cakephp-4.x, cakedc

First thanks for reading my question. I'm working on a website based on CakePHP 4 with CakeDC users installed. By default this plugin is using the url website/login to allow user to login. Because I want to change the redirect based on a parameter I have 2 options to follow.

- Create an addition login url.For example website/specialLogin
- Allow the system to use the default login with an url parameter. For example website/login/customparameter. This parameter can then trigger a different redirect url.

I have tried both option but in both case I run into the issue that I get the error from cake:
'Login URL `http://website:8888/loginShoppingCart` did not match `CakeDC/Users` or `Users` or `login` or ``.',

I have tried to find information that leads me to the root cause, but it seems the in some way Cakedc is using the cakephp urlchecker, but I do not understand how I can extend or alter the system so that it will allow me to use one of the options from my bullet list.

Does anybody knows how to change this so I can use or a custom additional URL (preferred) or URL parameters.

Any piece of information could potentially help to get this resolved.

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

The plugin provides a number of events you can use to modify the behavior, for example this one https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Events.md `Users.Authentication.afterLogin`.

It's triggered after a successful login and provides a way to redirect to a specific page. After dispatching your code, if you return a data array, the plugin will redirect to the specific url.

You can inspect the request and use a specific param or query param to redirect the user to a specific page, or redirect based on the user role for example.

Comment: This is indeed a good step forward, but maybe with your knowledge you can help me with 2 questions left. First one is how can I introduce a parameter, when directing the user to website/login/myeventparamater the system give an error as stated in my starting post. Second to confirm the afterLogin should be done in a custom users controller?

Comment: Adding a parameter is easy, in the return array you can use something like
    [
        'controller' => 'Posts',
        'action' => 'view',
        $yourParameterHere
    ]

Will generate '/posts/view/xxx'

The afterLogin event does NOT require a custom controller, you can listen to this event from your application without extending the CakeDC/Users.Users controller